# How can I set columns for an entire table in one UPDATE based on the SUM of a join table column?

Tags: mysql

I have tables  **companies** and **employees**:

```
 explain companies;
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| score              | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


 explain employees;
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| company_id         | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| score              | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

What I'd like to do is update the `companies.score` column based on the SUM of the `employees.score` column `where employees.company_id = companies.id`.

So given Company A and Company B, and Employee A1 (score 5), Employee A2 (score 2), and Employee B1 (score 3); I want to update Company A's score to 7, and Company B's score to 3.

What's the most elegant way to achieve this in MySQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update companies c set c.score = (select sum(e.score) from employees e where e.company_id = c.id);
```

Comment: Embarrassingly - I had the answer in the question :(

Answer (score 2):

Although a subquery based approach gives you valid results probably a better approach is to use a multi-table update syntax

```
UPDATE companies c JOIN
(
  SELECT company_id, SUM(score) score
    FROM employees
   GROUP BY company_id
) e
    ON c.id = e.company_id
   SET c.score = e.score;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ebb3e/1)** demo

Comment: Thanks for your input - why is joining on a subquery better than the answer provided by Balazs Papp?

Comment: You're quite welcome :) A correlated subquery is executed for **each row** in your update statement. When you do it with a JOIN **only two queries** are issued 1) to calculate totals and 2) to update